# Write a message to a given file in text mode

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Please give me an example how to write the message to a given file in Google  protocol buffer TEXT MODE ( not binary mode).

```
message S1
{
     required string name=1;
     required string family=2;
}

message S2
{
     repeated S1;
}
```

and how can read the text format from file if using this code for writing  message in file?

```
DebugString();
```

Comment: SO is not google, try to get an example from google. Here you are expected to show at least what you tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple to do so, using the [`Message::DebugString()`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message#Message.DebugString) function:

```
 S2 s2;
 std::ofstream out("S2.txt");

 out << s2.DebugString();
```